# Can someone please verify this number theory divisibility proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, contest-math

> Prove that the fraction $\displaystyle\frac{21n+4}{14n+3}$ is irreducible for every natural number $n$.

Ans:

Let's assume that there is some natural value of n for which the given fraction is reducible.That means $(21n+4)$ and $(14n+3)$ must have some common factor $y$, where $y\in \mathbb N$ and $y>1$.

So we can say that ,
$$21n+4=xy$$ and $$14n+3=yz$$  $[x,y,z \in \mathbb N]$

By multiplying the 1st equation by 2 and the 2nd equation by 3 and subtracting we get,

$$42n+8-42n-9= 2xy-3yz$$
Or,$$ -1= 2xy-3yz$$
Or, $$1= 3yz-2xy$$
Or, $$1= y(3z-2x)$$
Or, $$\frac 1y = 3z-2x$$

As 3z and 2x are both positive integers, the RHS has to be a whole number. But the LHS can only be whole if y=1. But it is a contradiction.

So, the fraction $\frac{21n+4}{14n+3}$ is irreducible for every natural number $n$.
Q.E.D.

Comment: Looks good to me, except I would put implies arrow instead of Or.

Comment: I suggest you learn mathjax using [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you want a shorter proof, you can use the converse of [Bezout’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). Otherwise, your solution is pretty good.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions 

Comment: You can show $21n + 4$ and $14n + 3$ have no common factor lot more easily: $3(14n + 3) - 2(21n +4 ) = 1$.

Comment: @Rishi - isn't that exactly what he did?

Comment: @SuzuHirose I didn't read it thoroughly. The fundamental idea would most likely be the same as the concepts of divisibility and non-divisibility don't change even if we change our approach. But the volume of work can certainly change.

Comment: Directly by working through the Euclidean algorithm we can get that they're relatively prime in a couple steps, $\gcd(21n+4,14n+3)=\gcd(7n+1,14n+3)=\gcd(7n+1,1)=1$.